# Python Unknown exception: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Netmiko module

Tags: python, paramiko

I am running the below script, not sure why its not running. I am using it to connect with a network device using the `netmiko` module

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

sh_run = {'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'ip': '152.120.12.34', 'username': 'selvam', 'password': '09629737', 'port': 22}
net_connect = ConnectHandler(**sh_run)
output = net_connect.send_command("show run | i authentication")
print(output)
```

I am running on pycharm tool in windows10x64 machine and got below error.

> Unknown exception: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found.
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
>   1888, in run
>           self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line
>   75, in parse_next
>           return self._parse_kexdh_reply(m)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line
>   114, in _parse_kexdh_reply
>           self.transport._verify_key(host_key, sig)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
>   1747, in _verify_key
>           key = self._key_infoself.host_key_type
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 62,
>   in **init**
>           ).public_key(default_backend())
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends__init__.py",
>   line 15, in default_backend
>           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl__init__.py",
>   line 7, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py",
>   line 53, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py",
>   line 13, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\ssh_dispatcher.py",
> ```
>
> line 168, in ConnectHandler
>           return ConnectionClass(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py",
>   line 187, in **init**
>           self.establish_connection()
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py",
>   line 650, in establish_connection
>           self.remote_conn_pre.connect(**ssh_connect_params)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 392,
>   in connect
>           t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
>   545, in start_client
>           raise e
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
>   1888, in run
>           self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line
>   75, in parse_next
>           return self._parse_kexdh_reply(m)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\kex_group1.py", line
>   114, in _parse_kexdh_reply
>           self.transport._verify_key(host_key, sig)
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line
>   1747, in _verify_key
>           key = self._key_infoself.host_key_type
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\venv\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 62,
>   in **init**
>           ).public_key(default_backend())
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends__init__.py",
>   line 15, in default_backend
>           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl__init__.py",
>   line 7, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\backends\openssl\backend.py",
>   line 53, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl import binding
>         File "C:\Users\selvam\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\bindings\openssl\binding.py",
>   line 13, in 
>           from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
>       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: It's better not to format at all, instead of bad formatting (like the traceback). Do you have *OpenSSL* package installed (considering that `cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl` is linked dynamically to its libs)?

Comment: yes, its already installed.

Comment: Another thing (that I forgot to include in my prev comment) the *Python* (set from *PyCharm*'s *Project interpreter*) architecture (32/64 bit) must match *OpenSSL*'s.